# multiple shared libraries from one project with common source files

Tags: c++, qt, dll, shared-libraries, qt-creator

I have a main application wich can be controlled by dynamically loaded plugins (.dll on win - .so on linux). Now i want to create a lot of these plugins where just on function is implemented different.

Lets say i have the following files in my Project:

- plugin.h
- plugin.cpp
- i001.cpp

i001.cpp contains one implementation of the of the "run" function of my plugin class. Now this Project compiles to "plugin.dll".

What i want to achieve is something like this:

- plugin.h + plugin.cpp + i001.cpp --> i001.dll
- plugin.h + plugin.cpp + i002.cpp --> i002.dll
- plugin.h + plugin.cpp + i003.cpp --> i003.dll
- plugin.h + plugin.cpp + i004.cpp --> i004.dll

Is there an easy way to get these outputs out of one project?
I'm using Qt-Creator on both Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to solve the problem.

1. You should use subprojects. Extract your common source-files into separate subproject as static library. More info [here](https://wiki.qt.io/SUBDIRS_-_handling_dependencies)
2. You may create .pri file:

   ```
   SOURCES += plugin.cpp
   HEADERS += plugin.h
   ```

and include it in all .pro files:

```
include(deployment.pri)
```